# Scala multiline string extraction using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, scala

Given a collection of strings which start all with prefix `_abc_ABC(` and end with suffix `)`, for instance,

```
val a = """_abc_ABC(
{
  x = 1
  y = 2
})"""
```

how to define a regular expression that strips out the prefix and suffix above ?

Comment: Must it be a regex? Simple String manipulation might be easier.

Comment: @semptic true, `stripPrefix` and `stripSuffix` would make it, yet would like to know with regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
val a = """_abc_ABC(
{
  x = 1
  y = 2
})"""

val Re = """(?s)_abc_ABC\((.*)\)""".r
a match { case Re(content) => println(content) }
```

The `(?s)` makes it match over multiple lines.